# Using Spring HATEOAS ControllerLinkBuilder and Kotlin throws IllegalArgumentException

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-hateoas

I'm making a small HATEOAS spring boot app using Kotlin.  I want to use the `ControllerLinkBuilder` to automatically create my HAL response links from the class that deals with them, like so:

```
user.add(linkTo(methodOn(UserController::class.java).findByName(userName)).withSelfRel())
```

but this throws:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class UserController
```

because all classes in Kotlin are final by default.  I'm not keen (and don't want to get in the habit of) making all my classes `open` just to get around this limitation.

I also don't really want to manually build up my links as they may change (and the `ControllerLinkBuilder` is very handy for populating parameters etc.

Currently I'm thinking I'm just going to have to accept that my controller classes have to be open.  Is there another way around this?

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not keen (and don't want to get in the habit of) making all my classes open

You only need to make your controllers open.  And it is a design feature of the framework you are using that subclassing is required.  There is no way to work around the inability to subclass a `final` class.  The JVM is enforcing the rule.  So you need to make those open.

There are other frameworks that do not require subclassing to produce similar functionality.

Comment: Just out of curiositiy: What other frameworks provide similar functionality?